# Find the element on i th index without sorting and in O(n) complexity

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

Recently I came across a question,

There is an unsorted array of n elements. Once we sort the array,
**i** th index will have an element. How would you find which element is going to be present on **i** th index in `O(n)` complexity on the unsorted array?

I tried many methods, finally I came to a conclusion that we may need to use an hash map. But later I found that hash map implementation usually follow a tree structure which has an `log n` complexity in insertion.

How shall I proceed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: **Hash** maps (as their name might suggest) are implemented using **hash** tables (which have an amortized insertion complexity of `O(1)`). Otherwise they would be called **tree** maps and be implemented using binary search **trees** (and have an amortized insertion complexity of `O(log(n))`). ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Linear Time Selection algorithm. Its running time is O(n) in the worst case. You can find its description in chapter "9.3 Selection in worst-case linear time" of [Introduction to Algorithms, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937) or on the Internet e.g. [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/cs423/lectures/selection-4up.pdf).
You can also use Randomized select algorithm. It has the expected linear time. You can find its description in chapter "9.2 Selection in expected linear time" of the same book.